# How to make customize sublime color scheme for myself to take effect?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I have create a customize color scheme for sublime 3.

[image]

The file like this.

Now I want to take effect in my sublime 3. But I don't know where should I put this file in. And how to let it work.

Answer (score 1):

Run sublime text and Preferences -> Browse Packages and put your file in folder User. Restart sublime. Installed color schemes can be turned off from the menu Preferences -> Color Scheme. I think that should help.